# Applying Stylesheet to one element

Tags: html, css

How would I make a footer and include it with phps include function from an external file but make it so that the stylesheet inside of it only applies to the footer and not the whole page. I have to link stylesheets using the head tag and that'll make it apply to the whole page when I include it. Any idea how I could manage to do this?

Comment: I already explained that when I do that it will apply the styles to the whole page not just the part thats included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include it as an iframe.
That way the css of your website won't interfere with your footer, and the styles of that iframe won't affect yours. 
If you wish to manipulate the styles of the footer, you have to use javascript then.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<HEAD></HEAD>


blah blah blah


<script type="" src="">
blah blah blah
</script>


<html>
```

Comment: I don't really understand, that wasn't very helpful.

Comment: Ur just wrapping your element in script tags

Comment: What would the script type be? text/css? And would the src be the css file? Because script tags don't tag css as a type of script.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize you wanted to do this from php. Read your question wrong. I don't know a lot about php so i cant help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your stylesheet for the footer.

If your footer container has an id of 'footer', then just add that id selector at the beginning of each item of the stylesheet

e.g.

```
table {
    /*attributes*/
}
```

becomes

```
#footer table {
    /*attributes*/
}
```

remember too, comma separated lists need the #footer added to each item

e.g.

```
div .item, span .value{
    /*attributes*/
}
```

becomes

```
#footer div .item, #footer span .value{
    /*attributes*/
}
```

You shouldn't need to add #footer to items that are already ids, but rather make sure the ids are not used for more than one element

e.g the following does not need to be changed:

```
#disclaimer{
    /*stuff*/
}
```

If doing this would cause problems for other areas that use the same stylesheet, then you may want to have some duplication in there.

If you don't want duplication, you can parse the css sheet on the server, and using some kind of regex replacer, insert #footer dynamically, and then serve that to the client in place of the original stylesheet. That's a lot of effort to go to though.

If you've got a long stylesheet  then I feel for you.

Comment: The stylesheet is 1689 lines. Any other ideas?

Comment: added this:If you don't want duplication, you can parse the css sheet on the server, and using some kind of regex replacer, insert #footer dynamically, and then serve that to the client in place of the original stylesheet. That's a lot of effort to go to though.